# Why does Facebook mobile sharing strip square brackets from escaped fragment?

Tags: facebook, deep-linking, prettyphoto, photoswipe

I have URLs like this:
`http://justifiedgrid.com/#!jig[1]/ML/8869`

They are deeplinking to a lightbox. It allows **individual sharing of each photo** with corresponding text as I prepare the page for Facebook bot based on the ID. The square bracket is entirely optional and could change it in the future, but for now it's a prettyPhoto legacy pattern. This works fine **except when shared to Facebook via the mobile app**. When shared, it's seen in the feed as:

`http://justifiedgrid.com/#!jig`

Clearly there is a cutoff at the brackets. Is there a way around it or should I change the brackets to safer characters? Everything after `#!` is the *escaped fragment*.

I stand on this URL on Android Chrome and from the browser menu I choose Share, then pick Facebook and it gets shared the wrong way. When I'm logged-in to Facebook using the browser itself and using the sharer dialog from share link/button (not the app's) it works fine.

Comment: Try with precent encoded characters: `%5B1%5D` instead of `[1]`

Comment: How do I do that if the browsers dedoce that in the URL bar? I use it for the "share button" and it works fine that way. Seems like I can't influence when people use the the chrome browser app's share option or facebook app's builtin browser's share feature.